# Profile Login Hour Restriction

Tags: profile, configuration

We need to disable login to salesforce org for specific profiles from Saturday 13th April 2 AM EST to Sunday 14th April 10 AM EST.

Will these login hours restrictions at profile level work, if we set them around Friday 12th April.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that would work.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox

Answer (score 0):

As per salesforce documentation : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_profiles_epui_login_hours_edit.htm&type=5,  this should be the setting :

[image]

From salesforce docs :

To let users log in at any time, click Clear all times.
To prohibit users from logging in on a specific day, set Start Time to 12 AM and End Time to End of Day.

What i found

setting start time to 12 AM and end time to End of day does not prohibit users from logging in on a specific day.